# clip-path property does not work in chrome

Tags: css, svg

my code work in IE and Firefox.But it don't work with chrome

svg code:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="960px" height="560px" viewBox="0 0 960 560" enable-background="new 0 0 960 560" xml:space="preserve">
 <clipPath id="clipPath">
          <polygon points="0,0 0,500 394,500 394,117 407.697,99.803 394,83 394,0    "/>
      </clipPath>
</svg>
```

css code:

```
.page article{
  width:48%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index:2;
  padding:2% 5% 2% 2%;
  clip-path:url(img/descripation_backgro_page1.svg#clipPath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has a limitation, when using external SVGs:

„Partial support refers to supporting shapes and the url(#foo) syntax for inline SVG, but not shapes in external SVGs.“

Source: http://caniuse.com/css-clip-path